Styling Material UI TextField label position
Is there any way to style the label of MUI TextField to be on top, just above the border? I can use this InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} to make the label always on top, but the default style is like a small label over the border. But I don't need label as overlay on border.
So basically I need to change this style

To something like this


Custom Style the Label: Add custom CSS to adjust the position of the label so that it sits just above the border, and adjust other properties like font size, padding, or margin as needed.
import { styled } from '@mui/system';

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)({
  '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
    transform: 'translate(0, -1.5rem) scale(1)', // Moves label above border
    fontSize: '1rem', // Adjust the font size as needed
    paddingLeft: '0.5rem', // Optional: Adjust padding for better alignment
    paddingRight: '0.5rem', // Optional: Adjust padding for better alignment
  },
  '& .MuiInputLabel-shrink': {
    transform: 'translate(0, -1.5rem) scale(1)', // Ensures consistent positioning when focused
  },
});

const MyComponent = () => (
  <StyledTextField
    label="First Name"
    variant="outlined"
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true,
    }}
  />
);

export default MyComponent;

